# Python JSON Parsing example

Tags: json, python-2.7, parsing

```
{
    "fruits" : {
        "fruit" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "apple",
                "size" : 1,
                "price" : 1
            },
            {
                "name" : "banana",
                "size" : 1,
                "price" : 2
            }
        ]
    },
    "sports" : {
        "sport" : [
            {
                "name" : "baseball",
                "population" : 9
            },
            {
                "name" : "soccer",
                "population" : 11
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my example json file.
I made this file.
If this format is not JSON, please tell me.

I want to get name's value. Using Python.
I can read JSON file and be converting dictionary.
But can't read Specific (tag's maybe) value

```
import json

#json file reading
with open('C:\Users\sub2\Desktop\example.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

#dictionary key
dic_key = []
for i in data:
    dic_key.append(i)

#dictionary value
for i in dic_key:
    print data[i] 

#name tag
for i in dic_key:
    for j in data[i]:
        print j.get('name')
```

How do get the name's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you all names

```
import json

#json file reading
with open('out.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

#dictionary key
dic_key = []
for i in data:
    dic_key.append(i)

#dictionary value
for i in dic_key:
    print data[i] 

#name tag
for i in dic_key:
    for j in data[i]:
        for k in data[i][j]:
            print k.get('name')
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate that.